# Regex match strings less than 150 chars in length

Tags: regex

I've been having no luck with a simple regex to match strings with 150 or less characters to alert my users of descriptions being too short.

These description values can contain any character/number with no specific pattern. Can someone with regex knowledge lend a hand?

Comment: errr have you tried string.length() rather than a regex to figure out the that string is less that 150 characters long?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: Your title and the question are conconsistent. Do you want to match "less than 150", or "150 or less"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately `.length` isn't an option. I'm implementing the regex as a conditional statement in a CMS that only accepts regex matches.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
^.{0,150}$
```

This will match a whole string containing between 0 and 150 (inclusive) of any character. Though regular expressions are probably the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was close, I was trying `*.^{0,150}$` to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Regex is overkill, just check the length of the string.

Comment: Unfortunately `.length` isn't an option, this isn't a jquery/javascript question and the implementation is not (and cannot be) javascript/jquery. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Regex for search in Sublime text editor, not as part of a program/script

Comment: sometimes you are forced to use regex